# issue with dynamic forms in redux Foms

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js, redux-form

I am facing a couple of issues with my dynamic form ( add, remove fields ) using redux form (redux-form/immutable).

- Validation fails for dynamically added fields, since initialValues doesn't have a default value for it.
- When I remove a newly added field after having added some text to it, the text entered shows up in a field I add subsequently.

I have gone through Erik Rasmussen's presentation here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDTi7lYR1VU&feature=youtu.be , and I am following a similar approach.

I can see the form data in the state using redux devtools. Also, I found in the documentation that we can change the form's state. ( http://redux-form.com/6.4.0/docs/api/ReducerPlugin.md/ )

I am trying to see if I can make it work using this. Will update my observations/findings here. Please let me know if there is an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [FieldArrays](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/fieldArrays/) solves the problem. It takes care of updating the form state in redux in a proper way. Earlier I was just using Fields and iterating over List stored in the component's state and modifying it on add/delete.